# Revert UI on Big Sur?

Tags: finder, menu-bar, ui, big-sur

How can I revert the Big Sur UI changes, especially Finder's?

While it looks cleaner, it now takes 2 clicks to change the Finder's view type of gallery, list, icons, or columns.
I would rather have the old UI and use 1 click.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18):

You can revert application toolbars to their 10.x look by setting `NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle`.

```
defaults write -g NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false
```

`-g` sets this globally (all applications), or you can specify a bundle identifier for a single app. Restart the application for the change to take effect (restart Finder with `killall Finder`).

[image]

---

However, I think your Finder window is too small, it's still just one click to change those settings with macOS 11 UI.

[image]

Comment: As of Monterey beta 4, this no longer works

Answer (score 10):

I would say that even one click is too much. It's waste to raise your hands from keyboard. Instead of clicking there are simple keyboard shortcuts for views in Finder:

[image]

Comment: A good suggestion perhaps, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, this is not an answer to the question. Answer is already provided by grg (there is no 'two clicks', just drag Finder window wide enough and it's 'one click'). My suggestion was about avoiding even this one click. I believe that productivity was main driver in need to reduce two clicks to one so why not take one step further in this direction.