# Always show directory icon on Finder on Big Sur

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

The default finder window looks like this:[image]

If I click on the folder name (AdventOfCode) twice, first a popup with the path opens, and then the directory icon stays, until I click again or move out of the "label area".

[image]

Does anyone know how to avoid the hiding of this icon?

Comment: [I wonder if this reversion helps for your situation.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408488/5472)

Comment: Also note that holding shift will ensure this icon appears right away

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can revert application toolbars to their 10.x look by setting `NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle`. To set this for Finder, use `com.apple.finder` as the domain.

Disclaimer (from the comments):

> I always wish “killall Finder” had a disclaimer. It’s safer to log out and back in since killing finder can interrupt copies, spoil mounted share and other such items... they are clearly edge cases...

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false
killall Finder
```

> [image]

From my answer to a similar more generic question: [Revert UI on Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/408475/37797)

Comment: I always wish “killall Finder” had a disclaimer. It’s safer to log out and back in since killing finder can interrupt copies, spoil mounted share and other such items...   they are clearly edge cases...

Comment: I usually prefer to hit cmd-option-esc and Relaunch Finder.

Comment: I lived with grg's answer for quite some time. But I still love the minimal style of Big Sur at the same time. Then I discovered an option in Onyx, turn off delay of displaying the proxy icon. This option immediately show the directory icon as soon as mouse is over there. I think you'll like it better too.

Comment: @VOX and you don’t need Onyx for that! https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419355/37797

Comment: As of Monterey this isn't working :( But this answer mention Monterey specifically, it's an Accessibility setting now https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419355/116544

Answer (score 5):

Enable "Show window title icons" option from "System Preferences" app => "Accessibility" => "Display" Section. [Refer screenshot] [Only available in Monterey macOS, not in Big Sur macOS]

[image: Accessibility options]

Comment: Thanks! I'm on 11.6 (20G165) and the option doesnt' exist. I assume you are running Monterey? :-D

Comment: On Ventura, macOS 13, this is in System Settings → Accessibility → Show window title icons.