# Draggable icon in the title bar?

Tags: big-sur

Previously, one could see an icon of the document in the title bar of any open window. For instance, In Pages there would be a small Pages icon to the left of the title of the document. I used these to save the document to new locations when I didn't know the original, for instance, when I opend it from Mail.

This does not appear to exist in Big Sur. I am missing it. Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: If I place the mouse during one second over the document name, the icon appears. Could you try if it works for you?

Comment: It does! Thanks! But wow, is the icon so much of a room-stealer that they had to hide it? How are you supposed to know it's there?!

Comment: File feedback: https://www.apple.com/feedback/ - I feel this is a huge regression.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I'm glad I could help! I've added an answer with an animated PNG to make the procedure clear. If the answer is useful, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Big Sur, you can make the proxy icon appear immediately on title hover:

```
defaults write -g NSToolbarTitleViewRolloverDelay -float 0
```

In macOS Monterey beta 3, you can make the icon always show:
**System Preferences** → **Accessibility** → **Display** → **Display** (tab) → **Show window title icons**

[image]

Enable this from the command line by setting

```
defaults write -g com.apple.universalaccess showWindowTitlebarIcons -bool YES
```

Answer (score 4):

The draggable icon in the title bar **is not gone in Big Sur, just hidden**.

To display it, simply place the mouse over the document name for a second, and it will appear. Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to remove the delay before the icon appears.

[image: Animation showing hovering on the title and the file icon appearing]

When the icon is visible, you can drag it to another folder as you desire.

Note that it is not necessary that the icon be visible if you just want to display the full path to the file. Either right-click the document title, or click the title while pressing the <kbd>command</kbd> key and it will appear instantly:

[image: Image showing the path to the file when command-clicked]