# How can I make the draggable titlebar file icon always appear at the top of files in Big Sur?

Tags: finder, pdf, icon, file

I don't know the nomenclature for this, but there used to be **always** a little file icon at the top of say, a pdf or jpeg which could be dragged to put the file somewhere else (eg paste it into an email).  It looked like this (I'm talking about the little icon to the left of the word 'gray's' in this screenshot):

[image: little file icon]

However, on Big Sur, the default behaviour for this little icon is **hidden** until I hover my mouse.  So, by default, I see this (*sans* icon):

[image: a picture without icon]

I would like this little  icon to **always** be present at the top of all files, like it used to be.  Is there a way to do this?

(My apologies for not knowing the name for this little icon!)

Comment: If it's only Preview where you want it as it "used to be", use `defaults write com.apple.Preview NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false` (quit and relaunch Preview).  If you want it everywhere, see the answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408475/revert-ui-on-big-sur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you upgrade to macOS Monterey (at least beta 3), you can make the icon always show:
**System Preferences** → **Accessibility** → **Display** → **Display** (tab) → **Show window title icons**

[image]

Enable this from the command line by setting

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccess showWindowTitlebarIcons -bool YES
```

Comment: Brilliant—I'm not normally a Beta user, but I can't wait for this to come to me downstream! Glad Apple has enabled a canonical answer..

Answer (score 2):

A note on @grg's terminal command to set the new option in macOS Monterey (I'd comment if I had enough reputation).

In order to get it working, I had to:

1. Give Terminal **Full Disk Access** via **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**
2. Remove the `-g` (global domain) option

So the command I ran and added to my `.macos` preferences script is:

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccess showWindowTitlebarIcons -bool true
```

Note: `YES` and `true` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your plist first. `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist`

Then run this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false
```

It will change the look of the toolbar so the title name is now on its own row above the tool icons. You can revert back to default with this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool true
```

Alternatively you can change the delay setting from the default 0.5 seconds to 0 seconds with:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSToolbarTitleViewRolloverDelay 0
```